# How can a user in MYSQL access the database from phpmyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, debugging, phpmyadmin

I made a user have privelages in the mySQL database. This allows the connection to be made. How would that user use phpMyAdmin? Whenever i try to use a remote database workbench, I sign in with the user's username and password, but it won't connect.

How do I also create a private mySQL file for login on the site?

Instead of the file saying:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$db = 'gallery';
```

how do I hide that information?

Comment: "It won't connect": any error message shown?

Comment: Lets say I use bluehost :X and I use the phpMyadmin. Now another user in that database also wants to use phpMyAdmin. How do I even allow that on my blue host account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I also create a private mySQL file for login on the site?

Several options:

- Best: Put the file outside of webroot and 'include' it in another PHP script
- OK: put the file in a specific folder and use a .htacess file to deny access to it ('deny from all')
- Least Good: if it's in a PHP script anyway then the server should not send those details to the client anyway (i.e. visit your actual script in the browser, you'll see nothing).

> How would that user use phpMyAdmin?

Hard to say with such little information, but it's probably a permissions issue with the user you've created. You may have to adjust the locations you're allowed access from on the user.

Answer (score 0):

According to Bluehost (https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/335) you cannot grant them access to your phpMyAdmin without giving them the domain password. However, according to https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/89 they can have access from a phpMyAdmin installed elsewhere, provided it's properly configured.

Comment: How does that user connect to the database from the sign in?

Comment: Using an account you create via cPanel's "MySQL databases" page. Did you try contacting Bluehost support?